# Why it is necessary to rejoin the domain after reverting the server from a snapshot?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, virtual-machines

I am totally new to this, in my project i have seen that it's required to rejoin servers to the domain after reverting them from a snapshot.

Can anyone please explain why this is needed and how it will affect the server if this step is skipped?   Also can I safely install IIS without joining it to the domain.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need to rebind the server to the domain is most likely related to the [30 day password](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295049) for computers.
When you restore a machine from snapshot, you're also reverting the password that machine knows and uses to authenticate to the domain. The domain will then refuse to service your computer. Re-adding it to the domain resets the password, and allows you to continue with business as usual.

Personally I would not install IIS until everything is 100%.
And most likely you want domain accounts for the services, which you can't set up until the machine has been joined.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to reset the computer account with the AD MMC. Or with Powershell

```
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword
```

or cmd

```
NETDOM RESETPWD /Server:<name of any domain controller> /UserD:<domain admin account> /PasswordD:<password>
```